# How should I implement max_size in a constant length STL-style data structure?

Tags: c++, stl, language-lawyer

Suppose I implement a constant length data structure comparable to a dynamic array. I.e., I give the data structure a length `l` in the constructor. Then, that instance of the data structure will never be able to hold more elements than `l`. I want that data structure to have an interface that is as close to STL as it can get.

How should I implement the `max_size` method for this class? Should it be the capacity `l` given in the constructor? Or should it be `std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max()`?

The documentation for this method says:

> Returns the maximum number of elements the container is able to hold
>   due to system or library implementation limitations, i.e.
>   std::distance(begin(), end()) for the largest container.

This documentation reads as if it is for the largest container, so it should be the latter definition. However, this method is a non-static method which hints at that it should return information about the current instance of the data structure, not a general limit for how big another instance of this data structure could get.

So what is the desired semantics of `max_size`? Max of this instance or max of a hypothetical "largest" instance?

Comment: See this example for `std::array`:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/max_size  Compare with `std::vector`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/max_size and make a choice that depends on the semantics of your class.

Comment: It's an std::array, but you should decide on what's best based on your application need, of which we have no idea.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: I have no application need for this, I never call this method. I just want the data structure to behave benign when somebody uses it in STL methods. I want to have a semantics that is consistent with what other STL methods or third party template libraries that might call this method would anticipate.

Comment: @RichardCritten: I know these two implementations, and that is the problem :). `std::vector` uses my latter definition, and `std::array` uses the former. My datastructure is somehow between them, so the very core of my question is which of the two to pick.

Comment: @gexicide only you can decide that - looks like you have a design decision to make.  SO is not the best site for these sort of questions.

Comment: @RichardCritten: It is not a design choice IMHO. It depends on what semantics standard interfaces inside STL rely on regarding this method. For example, if any method in STL would rely on the invariant that for each two instances of the same type `max_size()` must return the same value, then I would have to pick the latter semantics or I would violate the implicit contract these methods require. For example, there might be a copy method that anticipates this. I don't know whether such methods exist, but I want to be safe here, so I need to know the exact contract this method has to fulfill.

Answer (score 3):

Your container reminds me of some sort of dynamic `std::array`.

[`std::array::max_size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/max_size) has the semantics of your former definition (the maximum size of the current instance):

> Because each `std::array<T, N>` is a fixed-size container, the value returned by `max_size` equals `N` (which is also the value returned by `size`).

Comment: But what does that mean for my data structure? For a `std::array<T,N>` it makes sense, as every instance of this very instantiation can never hold more elements than `N`. But for my class-e.g., call it `dyn_array<T>`-there may be instances of the same instantiation that can hold more elements than other ones. The differences that the former is compile time constant per instantiation of the template while mine varies is an important consideration in this case, I guess.

Comment: @gexicide I would argue that they are in fact the same. The maximum amount of elements an instance of your container to hold is fixed, i.e. it can't grow like `std::vector`. This puts a limit on the maximum size of a specific container instance you are calling `max_size()` on.